# How to add an element in nested atom map - Clojure

Tags: collections, clojure

I getting that error: Cannot invoke "clojure.lang.IAtom.swap(clojure.lang.IFn, Object, Object)" because "atom" is null.

I want to add a keyword value in an atom map. Where am I doing mistakes?
(I tried reduce too)

```
(def !my-map (atom {1 {:id   1
                       :name {:first "ali" :last "veli"}}
                    2 {:id   2
                       :name {:first "batu" :last "can"}}}))
;expected output:
;        {1 {:id 1
;  :name {:first "ali" :last "veli" :fullname "ali veli"}}
;         2 {:id 2
;  :name {:first "batu" :last "can" :fullname "batu can"}}}


((fn [y]
   (let [{:keys [first last]} y]
     (swap! (get-in @!my-map [:name]) assoc :fullname (str first " " last))
     ))
 (for [len (range 1 (+ 1 (count @!my-map)))]
   (get-in @!my-map [len :name])
   )
;=> ({:first "ali", :last "veli"} {:first "batu", :last "can"})
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(swap! !my-map update-vals
       (fn [v]
         (update v :name
                 (fn [n]
                   (let [{:keys [first last]} n]
                     (assoc n :fullname (str first " " last)))))))
```

Comment: Thank you, when I read your code then my try looks very needless to me :)

Comment: Is it possible to write that code using fewer nested functions? It comes to me as hard to understand. Still trying to debug it to understand it.

Comment: Yes, as you saw in the answer by Martin. But it'll result in multiple accesses to the value under the `:name` key.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(swap! !my-map update-vals #(assoc-in % [:name :fullname]
                                      (str (-> % :name :first)
                                           " "
                                           (-> % :name :last))))
```

Result:

```
{1 {:id 1, :name {:first "ali", :last "veli", :fullname "ali veli"}},
 2 {:id 2, :name {:first "batu", :last "can", :fullname "batu can"}}}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a clear answer.

Comment: Ok, I did it without using an atom. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

i'd say that nice idea is to abstract out the updating function, since otherwise the intention quickly becomes invisible.

```
(defn attach-full-name [{{:keys [first last]} :name 
                        :as data}]
  (update data :name assoc :full (str first " " last)))


(swap! !my-map update-vals attach-full-name)

;; {1 {:id 1, :name {:first "ali", :last "veli", :full "ali veli"}},
;;  2 {:id 2, :name {:first "batu", :last "can", :full "batu can"}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(require '[com.rpl.specter :as s])
(->> !my-map
    (s/transform
        [s/ATOM s/ALL s/LAST :name (s/collect-one :first) (s/collect-one :last) :fullname]
        (partial apply format "%s %s")))
```